# Meteor Android geolocation

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am new to Meteor and I am developing simple Android map application using Meteor. One of the main functionality of my app is getting user's current location.

I using **GoogleMap JS API** ([map-geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)) and i am testing the following [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) for testing getting the current location by adding GoogleMaps code to **client/main.html** in Meteor project.

The example is working as expected on Webbrowsers but when i tried it on Android but it didn't work. The current problem i am facing that the HTML5 object **"navigator.geolocation"** is always null.

So my questions are:

- Is there anything special should i do in my Metero app to manage the map works on Android-Meteor?
- Do i need to add any permission to Meteor Android app? since i think my problem is permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative more 'Meteorish' method would be to use the [mdg:geolocation](https://atmospherejs.com/mdg/geolocation) package. I've used it on web and in my brief experience with it haven't noticed any issues on Android. It gives you a reactive data source too.